# Show Convergence in Distribution to an r.v. that is $N(0,3)$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

Let $(X_{j})_{j \geq 1}$ be i.i.d. with the uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$. Let $Y_{n}=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}}{\sum_{j}^{n}X_{j}^{2}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{j}^{3}}$. Show that $\sqrt{n}Y_{n}$ converges in distribution to $Z$, where $\mathcal{L}(Z)=N(0,3)$.

I'm not sure how to apply the Central Limit Theorem to what I have here. Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write 
$$\sqrt nY_n=\color{green}{\frac{\sum_{j=1}^nX_j}{\sqrt n}}\cdot \color{red}{\left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^nX_j^2+\sum_{j=1}^nX_j^3}n\right)^{-1}}.$$
Green term converges to $N(0,1)$, while red one's limit can be computed with the law of large number.

Then we use [Slutsky theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem).

Comment: I figured out what the red part converges to. But what does Slutsky's Theorem have to do with it?

Comment: Never mind - I just clicked on the link. That version of Slutsky's Theorem is not like the one in my textbook.